# tail unknown number of files with -f option

Tags: shell, tail

I have a shell script, which will create number of child processes and each of these processes output their log in a different file. I wanted something to tail all these files and output them in shell. The important part is that I do not know about the number of files before running the scripts. For two files I managed to do it like this:

```
unbuffer SOME COMMANDS  > OUT1.out &
unbuffer SOME_OTHER_COMMAND > OUT2.out &
tail -q -f OUT1.out -f OUT2.out --pid $!
wait
```

But now that I don't know about the number of processes I don't know how to do it with tail. If you have any other suggestion or ways to do it, I would like to here about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to monitor a directory for new files and then need to pass to `tail` or `tail` like commands. So either you need to implement your own directory monitoring code or you can use `multitail`

http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.php